# How to get data from '-' (hyphen) separated value in MySQL with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I want to get data from '-' (hyphen) separated values in MySQL database in Laravel 5.1.

For example:

**Table price:**

```
id  price  
1   100-200  
2   300-500  
3   500-700  
4   800-900
5   500  
6   1000-1500
```

Now I want to get data **greater than or equal to 400**.

Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
$query->where('price.'.price, '>=', 400)
```

but it returns all the data, but I want to get only relevant data.

Comment: I think that is a bad analyzed database, it's better if you have 3 columns instead of your 2 columns, that's `id | min-price | max-price` your sentences will be simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `substring_index` function if you are looking at the first digit from `price`

```
select * from price where 
substring_index(price,'-',1)+0 >=400
```

If you are looking between the range i.e. `300-500` is also considered then you can do as

```
select * from price where 
substring_index(price,'-',1)+0 >=400
or substring_index(price,'-',-1)+0 >=400
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `split_str` function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

And query to get using this function :

```
SELECT id, SPLIT_STR(price, "-", 1) AS p1
FROM price
HAVING p1 >= 400
```